# How to retrieve data using METADATA API and to change profile settings

Tags: api, custom-object, custom-field, metadata

What is the metadata endpoint url to get retrieve custom field/object/tab data?

For ex, I have been using this url -

> https://<instance_url>/services/Soap/m/28.0

to create custom objects.

Edit: Also, I am building an application to push custom object/tab/fields to a salesforce account on integration. While successfully pushing these, i am unable to change the tab visibility through api calls. This is my intended purpose. How do I proceed?

Edit2: I tried using this payload, but couldnt change the tab visibility settings. visits__c is the custom object that was created and VISITS is the custom tab

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Header>
  <ns1:SessionHeader soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xmlns:ns1="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
   <ns1:sessionId>*****</ns1:sessionId>
  </ns1:SessionHeader>
 </soapenv:Header>
 <soapenv:Body>
  <create xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <metadata xmlns:ns2="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" xsi:type="ns2:Profile">
    <applicationVisibilities>
        <application>Marketing</application>
        <default>false</default>
        <visible>true</visible>
    </applicationVisibilities>
    <custom>true</custom>
    <objectPermissions>
        <object>visits__c</object>
    </objectPermissions>
    <tabVisibilities>
        <tab>VISITS</tab>
        <visibility>Hidden</visibility>
    </tabVisibilities>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>APIEnabled</name>
    </userPermissions>
    </metadata>
  </create>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: There are several such APIs available; it really depends on your intended purpose. If you're building a third-party GUI, you probably want the REST API, while if you're building an IDE, you probably want the Tooling API, and if you're working with deploying changes between orgs, the Metadata API. The differences are contextual; the REST API gives you data for rendering a GUI, the Tooling API is more development tools, and the Metadata API is more of an administrative feature.

Comment: I am building an application to push custom object/tab/fields to a salesforce account on integration. While successfully pushing these, i am unable to change the tab visibility through api calls. This is my intended purpose. How do I proceed?

Comment: @MohanKrishnan you should really [edit] that comment into your question.

Comment: @MohanKrishnan In that case, it's essentially the same as your previous question, at least in the sense that I'd give you the same answer as the one before. To set *visibility* to a field, object, or tab, you use the *Profile* object. I suggest you re-read the previous answer and click on the links to learn about how to apply security settings to your fields, objects, and tabs.

Comment: @battery.cord done

Comment: @sfdcfox I have updated the question with the payload used.

Comment: @MohanKrishnan Its answers would be exactly same as previous question's answer. sfdcfox also mentioned the same thing. Please ask doubts under same question if any else close the question by selecting the answer. Go though the links provided in previous answer create correct payload.